# Black background when using a mini skin

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When ever I try to use a mini skin on Minecraft Pocket Edition for the iPhone it shows up, but the background is black and it is still the normal size person. I bought the skin and everything and to know it doesn't work disappoints me. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that Minecraft is replacing transparent parts of the skin image file with black. Only the secondary layers of skins can contain transparent parts (hats/hair for example).

This is to prevent people from cheating in say PVP where being invisible would be unfair.

It's also not possible to change the player size without modifying the game itself.